# How to remove the horizontal line below the image in the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

To add image in the header , I have written the code, basically the pagestyle modification. Now , just for a trial , I first modified only my `plain` page style. After the image gets inserted in the header , I get a horizontal line, How do I remove it?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wallpaper}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\section{blah blah blah}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare that you want a header line with no width:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\section{blah blah blah}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While Karl answered your question to the point, this is just another `tikz` crazy option to put some background material in only few pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\backgroundsetup{
pages=some,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[draw=green!50!blue,thick,fill=orange!30,rounded corners=1ex] at ($(current page text area.north) + (0,0in)$) {\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[4]
\section{blah blah blah}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant of above snippet will be

```
\backgroundsetup{
pages=some,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
position={0.55\textwidth,-0.1\textheight},    %%% this and 
contents={%
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}   %%% this also would work
}
}
```

In this case, you won't be needing

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
```